# Calling a function which calls Async mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I want to call a function that executes a query using **npm-mysql .query**  function. The problem is that .query is asynchronous so I get a returned value **= undefined** and after that the mysql.query finishes the execution.
I 've tried to use **promises** but I couldn't synchronize the return value with the mysql.query result.

1. I don't want to use sync-mysql.
2. I want it to be in a wrapper function as shown.

`function mysql_select(query)
{
    var json_result
    mysql_connnection.query(query, function (err, result) 
    {
        if (err) throw err
        json_result = JSON.stringify(result)
    })
    return json_result
}`

For example i want to call this function like this:

`console.log(mysql_select("SELECT * FROM table"))`

and dont get the undefined result 
I have checked the query , it returns the data correctly but after the function returns the json_result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look into Promises:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

```js
function mysql_select(query)
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        mysql_connnection.query(query, function (err, result) 
        {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve(JSON.stringify(result));
        })

    })
}

;(async function() {
    console.log(await mysql_select('SELECT * FROM table'));
})();
```

Comment: Thanks , Worked Perfectly ! i didn't know i could return a promise , this link is useful enough !